# Delete even/odd occurance numbers in an array with For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, switch-statement

I have an array as shown below, containing 6 numbers. I'm trying to create a function that deletes a value if it's an even/odd occurance. For example, if I type the function `deleteData(myArr,"even")`, it will remove data number 0th, 2nd, and 4th. And the other way around if it's "odd". But when I tried running my code, it didn't work the way i wanted it to go. Can anybody tell me why?

```
const myArr=[90,34,28,19,26,22];


function deleteData (array,occuranceType){
    switch (occuranceType){
        case "odd":
            for (let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                if (i%2!==0){
                    array.splice(i,1);
                };
            };
            break;
        case "even":
            for (let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                if (i%2==0){
                    array.splice(i,1);
                };
            };
            break;
    };
};

deleteData(arr,"odd")
console.log(arr)
```

This is the result in the console : `[ 90, 28, 19, 22 ]`

Comment: you need subtract 1 from `i` variable every time you remove an item.

Comment: Or you can start from the end

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this since it's easier and you don't mutate the original array.

```js
let myArr = [90, 34, 28, 19, 26, 22];

function deleteData(array, removeEven) {
  return array.filter((v, i) => removeEven ? (i % 2 !== 0) : (i % 2 === 0));
};

myArr = deleteData(myArr, true)
console.log(myArr)
```

Comment: You can also do as `array.filter((o, i) => (occuranceType === 'odd' ? !(i % 2) : i % 2))`

Comment: that was my first solution that I wanted to post, but I figured since it's only 2 choices, a `boolean` fits the scenario.

Comment: Yup, you are right

Comment: Why do you explicitly compare it with `0`?  We already know it's an integer. It doesn't bring any visual or performance benefit...in fact it looks much worse than `removeEven ? i % 2 : !(i % 2)`

Comment: It's not a performance benefit, it's just easier to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array based on the `pos` argument passed to the function.

```js
const deleteData = (array, pos) =>
  array.filter((_, i) => i % 2 === Number(pos !== "even"));

console.log(deleteData([90, 34, 28, 19, 26, 22], "odd"));
console.log(deleteData([90, 34, 28, 19, 26, 22], "even"));
```

**Note:** `Number(false)` returns `0` and `Number(true)` returns `1`.